# How to use Post to URL feature of plugin

Tags: php, url, post, get

I'm wondering if anyone could help me out in trying to use a feature of my form plugin (FormCraft for Wordpress) that allows the form data to be sent to a URL. There's no documentation on this feature and I can't figure it out. Here's a screenshot of the options:

[image]

I've created an empty `form_data.php` file and uploaded it to my site, then put that URL in the field seen in the screenshot. Nothing happens in the php file when I submit a form. The support team for the plugin hasn't been very helpful, they just said, "You need to make sure the script on that URL will catch and parse the data." Is there anything that I would need to add to the php file to get this to work?

Comment: which form plugin is it ?

Comment: The PHP file by it's own wont do anything, you need to add a set of "orders" on that PHP file, that will tell PHP what data to look at, and what to do with it.

Comment: It's FormCraft for Wordpress.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add PHP Code to your `form_data.php` to handle the form data. What code have you tried?

Comment: Actually, spend some time here: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Comment: @Twisty i need a post data print in html format in another page.
please give me a solution

Comment: @SavanDholu have you done the research and posted a question? The solution is out there. If you want help, you have to have started somewhere.

Comment: @Twisty Yes done the research

Comment: @SavanDholu then you either have an answer or a question. So what have you tried and what is your question?

Comment: @Twisty when submit from so all submitted data gos to another page and open a pfd format

Comment: @SavanDholu you have a lot of work ahead of you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Twisty i have print data another page but some fields are blank so not show in from

Comment: @SavanDholu have you posted a question or your current code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154505/discussion-between-savan-dholu-and-twisty).

Comment: @Twisty please send email id

Answer (score 1):

Send the data to this file below.

`http://localhost/bellow_file.php`

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$json = json_decode($json,true);
$data = "";

foreach ($json as $key => $val) {
  if(is_array($val)) {
    $data .= "$key:\n";
  } else {
    $data .= "$key => $val\n";
  }
}

file_put_contents('test.txt', $data);
?>
```

Comment: @xufor i need a post data print in html format in another page. please give me a solution